# Morph To Many Laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-relations

Question.php

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\User' , 'votable');
}
```

User.php

```
public function voteQuestions()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Answer', 'votable');
}
```

This shows up:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany::exits()

And Laravel tells you to:

> Did you mean Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany::get()?

Comment: Are you trying to call `exists` and you misspelled it in your code? If not, depending on where you are calling `exists()` perhaps you need to check if a relationship exists with `has('votes')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something is wrong in your MorphToMany relation.
You need something like this:

Question model:

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Vote' , 'votable');
}
```

Answer model:

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Vote' , 'votable');
}
```

Vote model:

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Question' , 'votable');
}

public function asnwers()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Answer' , 'votable');
}
```

But if you want to check relation existing, there is `has('relationName')` method.

`exists()` method work only for Eloquent Model instances.